# How do I activate HTTP JSON-RPC on a Geth node?

Tags: rpc

I want to use RPCs to access a Geth node.
Do I have to execute `admin.StartRPC` on the node in order to activate the RPC server?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `admin.startRPC(addr, port)`, when you start your node (if you are using geth) you can use the rpc flag

`geth --rpc` - this defaults to localhost:8545

You can also define your own address and port number with these options:

`geth --rpc --rpcaddr <ip> --rpcport <portnumber>`

`geth --rpc --rpccorsdomain "http://localhost:3000"`

[Documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#json-rpc-endpoint)

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this: `geth --rpcapi eth,net,web3 --rpccorsdomain * --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0`